# Can we interpret the probability of fails the same way than the probability of success in a binomial model?

Tags: r, logistic, modeling, interpretation

I have used the data "Chickweight" in R to make a dummy example model

```
data("ChickWeight")
ChickWeight$large = as.numeric(ChickWeight$weight>100)

mod = glm(large~Diet+Time, data=ChickWeight, family = binomial)
plot(mod)
summary(mod)

library(ggeffects)
plot(ggpredict(mod, "Time [all]"))
```

The summary of the model is:

```
Call:
glm(formula = large ~ Diet + Time, family = binomial, data = ChickWeight)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -6.63367    0.60391 -10.985  < 2e-16 ***
Diet2        1.08314    0.41139   2.633  0.00847 ** 
Diet3        2.24019    0.44153   5.074 3.90e-07 ***
Diet4        2.76862    0.46120   6.003 1.94e-09 ***
Time         0.52388    0.04429  11.829  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 800.44  on 577  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 299.80  on 573  degrees of freedom
AIC: 309.8

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 6
```

If I understand well, I could interpret this model by saying:
"The probability that chicks are large increases with time"

Would it be correct to say the opposite:
"The probability that chicks belong the the *small* category decreases statistically with time" ??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event

Comment: So... this also works with complex models with several predictors?